# How can I add a "method" to this hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, hash, oauth-2.0, omniauth

I'm writing a custom OAuth2 strategy. I need to add an `expired?` method to the hash response and I'm not sure how to do it. The response I'm getting gives me a time until expiry but not the expired method itself.

[image]

I need to add an expired? method to it, not sure how. Any help?

Comment: Is lib/strategies/canvas.rb your code, or a library/gem you are using?

Comment: It's my code. It's a custom strategy (with no docs, so it's loads of fun)

Comment: See my answer below to answer your direct question, but, that said, you could have also just written a function like `def token_expired?(access_token)` and call that on that line, like `if token_expired?(access_token)`.  Save the trouble of making a class.  But, I think based on what you're working on, perhaps the class will come in handy down the line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using a Hash directly, you could create a new class in `build_access_token` that extends it.

```
class AccessToken < Hash

  def initialize response_hash
    # This overrides the default behavior, you don't care here.
    # But if you do, just remove this and call merge manually.
    self.merge!(response_hash)
  end

  def expired?
    # return true if expired, false otherwise
  end

end
```

Then, in build_access_token, do something like:

```
token = AccessToken.new response_hash
```

Now, your object is not just `Hash`, but your "super-hash" `AccessToken`.  You could attach other methods as needed.

Further down the line, you could change this to take a "whitelisting" approach as well, taking a Hash in your constructor, only exposing the elements of that Hash that you want to expose to consumers via methods, and removing the Hash extension.  But the above should do you for now.

Comment: No problem.  Note I added a constructor methods to make this properly wrap the hash and merge the response_hash.  This will also make it possible to take the "whitelisting" approach I mentioned down the line, if you ever want to.  Happy coding!